# React component only displays status code error message instead of custom ones

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, promise, axios

During POST to register new user I check if that user already exists in mongoDB data base and if yes display this in react near the register form. I'm using express.js to create my API and axios to send requests from client side. This is how I check if user is registered.

```
const user = await Model.User.findOne({email: req.body.email});
if(user) return res.status(400).send('User already registered');
```

This is the function that is being called on Register button click:

```
handleSubmit= async (userData) =>{
    await apis.registerNewUser(userData)
    .then(res => console.log(res.body))
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        this.setState({errorMessage: err.message});
    })   
}
```

The problem is that I can't display the custom error message that I add when sending response. Instead of getting "User already registered" I get "400 Bad request" showing near my register form. When I post through postman there is no problem, the response "User already registered" shows up in the response text window however that part doesnt exist when recieving error on react side. I can't send user an error that tells him nothing about the reason why he can't register. How can I get "User already registered" in react?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. In order to read the property of that custom text put inside send() when catching error I need to read from err.response.data - that's the right property to read "User already registered".I hope it helps someone one day.